# How do I sum numbers inside a string sentence already stored in sql column using php or sql

Tags: php

```
MEL1INFA73 Confirmed. Ksh29.00 sent to Safaricom Offers  for account Tunukiwa on 21/5/18 at 3:29 AM New M-PESA balance is Ksh5.50. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.
```

An example of the string sentence is as above and the layout in sql table is as below:

[image]

Comment: and have you **tried anything yourself** so far? because we're here to help with your problem, but not do your job for you. you have to show some effort at least.

Comment: I know how to do it in C++ but I have no idea when it comes to php and sql..

Comment: Is ksh the currency?

Comment: yeah Ksh is Currency Symbol @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all (regex) and array_sum.

The regex captures all digits with leading ksh and optional space.

Array_sum sums the digits captured in the regex, since preg_match returns a multidimensional array with 0 being the full match and 1 being the capture.

```
$str ='MEL1INFA73 Confirmed. Ksh29.00 sent to Safaricom Offers  for account Tunukiwa on 21/5/18 at 3:29 AM New M-PESA balance is Ksh5.50. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.';

preg_match_all("/ksh\s*(\d+\.\d+)/i", $str, $matches);
echo array_sum($matches[1]); //34.5
```

https://3v4l.org/A2oNM